# Evolution tasks not showing in the panel

Tags: 11.04, evolution, indicator

Evolution tasks do not show in the clock applet in Ubuntu 11.04.

I like to see the tasks side to the appointments in the clock applet.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards

Comment: @fossfreedom I have same [problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/659335/evolution-calender-event-not-showing-in-panel-date-menu) so we should open this question again

Comment: @edwardtorvalds - you have correctly handled this by creating a new question.  If necessary - when you get your answer we may/should dupe this one against yours.