# Evolution Calender event not showing in panel date menu

Tags: panel, evolution

I have entered an event in Evolution but it is not showing in panel's date menu. Also I have selected `Monthly calender` and `Coming events from Evolution Calender` in System Settings > Time & Date > Clock tab

Answer (score 1):

What version of Evolution are you using? For me in 14.04 LTS the Software Center shows 3.10.4-0ubuntu2. (Although there is a newer one available). I needed from optional add-ons:

1. Standard plugins for evolution (evolution-plugins)
2. GNOME panel indicator applet for Evolution (evolution-indicator)

`sudo apt-get install evolution-indicator`

`sudo apt-get install evolution-plugins`

And in Evolution>Edit>Plugins>Enable Both.

If you use Google Calenders, then there is a as well a workaround without need of Evolution:
http://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/view-your-google-calendar-events-in-the-ubuntu-unity-panel/

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/calendar-indicator-displays-google.html

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install calendar-indicator
```